# Get only positive long from murmur3 guava

Tags: java, hash, guava

I'm using java murmur3 from guava lib to get long values representing hash. Is there any possibility to get only positive long numbers? Right ow guava returns +/- results which is not good for me..

I use murmur3 to convert string ids to numerical representation because of caclculation framework limitations. I do not afraid of small quantity of collisions. But I'm afraid just to take abs(murmur3Value). It should significantly raise probability of collisions. Am I right?

I have ~ 1*10^8 unique ids, is it ok to abs their hased values and not to get too many collisions.

i don't have any collistions on 10^7 values, but hashed are positive and negative, i would like to use only positive values.

Comment: Whats wrong with taking the absolute value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `Math.abs` is wrong... as `Math.abs(Long.MIN_VALUE) == Long.MIN_VALUE`. It's also needlessly slow, given that there are simple options:

```
x >>> 1
```

and

```
x & Long.MAX_VALUE
```

In any case you lose one bit, either the most or the least significant one. I guess in case of Murmur3 it doesn't matter.

---

Concerning collision, it really shouldn't matter what operation you choose - you'll have `2**63`, i.e., about `9e18` different hashes. With `1e8` inputs, it means that collision are very rare if any (I'm to lazy to look up the formula).

Comment: I will delete my answer, didn't think it through

Comment: I'm using mumrmur3 to hash string based user_ids and feed them to mahout. Guys from mahout user group say that mahout feels bad when it get's negative ids... That is why I want to use fast hash with possible collisions (it's ok for the task) and avoid negative numbers.